# Jquery: Change HTML content of jqXHR from Get Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a separate HTML file that I am loading in via `$.get()` and then turning into a Bootstrap modal dialog:

```
$.get("src/html/foobar.html", function (data) {
    var md = $(data).modal({
        backdrop:'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
});
```

However, before I turn this into a modal dialog and show it, I want to load in some content from the server. We know from [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) that `$.get()` returns a `jqXHR` object. Is there a way to somehow change the content of the HTML returned in the `data` before I show it as a modal?

EDIT: I should be a little more specific and ask what operations can I perform on the object to edit its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, of course, just modify `data` inline within your callback function before passing it to `.modal`

However a neater mechanism is to just chain a `.then` call from the `Promise` that is the `jqXHR` object:

```
$.get(url).then(function(data) {
    // modify the data here
    ...
    return modified_data;
}).then(function(data) {
    // show data modally
});
```

NB: this assumes jQuery 1.8 or later, with the improved (i.e. corrected) semantics for `.then`

To avoid writing lots of inline functions, make the modifier function and the modal function separate named functions, then you can write:

```
$.get(url).then(modify).then(display);
```

Promises are the "new" way (since jQuery 1.5) to allow for separation of responsibility - as you can see from the example above the Promise chain allows you to completely detangle the three separate acts of retrieving, modifying and subsequently displaying the remote data.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should of been a little more specific. I am trying to figure out the `// modify the data here` part. More or less how would I perform operations such ID selections `$('#foo')` on this variable.

Comment: @LoganLehman  Just load'em up into a jQuery variable, without adding them to the DOM, e.g. `var $els = $(data)`